# How to work with form having different types of answer type such as radio,checkbox,date,textbox etc

Tags: selenium

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjW3d.png]My script fill up the form through the script but now wanted to have console output alongwith answers and section/subsections name.

Please refer 2 images [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdREY.png), [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5MiO.png) which individually running successfully but I need to combine these 2 where I am finding difficulty.

The form have in all 11 sections, Each section contain Heading, Sub-heading(s), and question(label) and its answer type which can be text,date,radiobutton,checkbox etc.
As shown in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ioafg.png) each section has the `div[class='questions-parent-container']` which contains number of `div[@class='answers-container col ng-star-inserted']`.

Please refer 3 images which will give you idea about each section contain how many questions?. [screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R3tb.png),[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3Sdo.png), [screeshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHmNu.png).

I am not able to find the total number of questions section wise.

Please refer the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa9Bx.png), and [another image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAQP6.png) for the class='TextBox', either only label is there or label as well input textbox. Through random function its entering the random string but finding difficulty to print it as some Textbox contains only label.
I just want to have output the entire form alongwith section,subsection name and all questions with answers.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: could you post your code in your question? Images of code is not a good practice.

Comment: I have posted  images of because its such a long code and was little difficult to explain. Next time will keep it in mind. Thanks.

Comment: @Amruta, please help i got stuck, not able to find the solution.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me . what u want to do ..you want  to combine code or print heading subheading and questions or having issues with xpath?

Comment: As per our discussion over chat i am going to put the answer here. Please verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to navigate to the sub-child of child of parent, use xpath or css. First you have to locate the parent then traverse till child:

```
List<WebElement> answers =driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class='questions-parent-container']>div>div>div"));

System.out.println(answers.size()); // this will give you total answers unders that question container

for(webElement answer: answers)  // Now Iterate over answers list to get class attribute
{
String answerType= answer. getAttribute("class");  //It will give you whether it is Textbox, dropdown, radio button or checkbox

//Now you can perform any actions based on your answerType using if-else loop or Switch-case staements.

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much its worked for me.But having one more issue with it is when trying to print label and random string(as it answer),, its not printing in order, it always printing the Random string first and then 'Label'.  I hereby attach the screenshot to make it more clear.

Comment: <div _ngcontent-afw-c77="" class="answers-container col ng-star-inserted"> <div class="TextBox"><app-input  inputtype="text" _nghos-afw-c24="" class="ng-untohed ng-pristin ng-valid ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontn-afw-c24=""><div _ngcontent-afw-c24="" class="input ng-star-inserted"><div  class="col-sm-12 col-md"><div _ngcontent-afw-c24="" class="form-group"><label _ngcontent-afw-c24="" aria-hidden="true" class="ql-editor ng-star-inserted" for="Last">Last </label><div _ngcontent-afw-c24=""><input class="form-control ng-untouche ng-star-inserted" type="text" id="Last"  aria-label="Last ">

Comment: for(int ans=0; ans<answers.size(); ans++){ String answerType = answers.get(ans).getAttribute("class"); try { if(answerType.equals("TextBox")) { 
WebElement tlabel = answers.get(ans) .findElement(By.tagName("label"));
syso(tlabel.getText()); if(answers.get(ans).findElement(By.xpath("//app-input[@inputtype='text']/div/div/div/div[@class='form-group']/div"))!= null){
WebElement textbox = answers.get(ans).findElement(By.xpath("//app-input[@inputtype='text']/div/div/div/div[@class='form-group']/div/input"));
textbox.sendKeys(getSaltString());System.out.println(textbox.getAttribute("value"));}}